# $\operatorname{Spin}^+(s,t)$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I'm reading materials on spin groups. Let $Cl(s,t)$ be the Clifford algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{s+t}$ with standard bilinear form $\eta$ with signature $(s,t)$. The book then defines, $$\operatorname{Spin}^+(s,t)=\{v_1…v_{2p}w_1…w_{2q}\mid\eta(v_i,v_i)=1,\eta(w_j,w_j)=-1; \ p,q\geq 0\}$$
and said this forms a group. But, I don't see how can this be true? Since $v_i$ and $w_j$ are not necessarily be orthogonal with respect to $\eta$, we can not anti-commute $v_i$ and $w_j$, then how can a product like $w_1w_2v_1v_2$ be still in $\operatorname{Spin}^+(s,t)$?

EDIT: For those of you who met the same problem when reading the book Mathematical Gauge Theory by J.D. Hamilton, the following link contains a list of updates of the book including this point (350 (6)), it turns out this indeed it's a subgroup.

https://maththeoryphysics.com/

Comment: I guess that might be an error. In [Brian Weber's notes for Math 651 in 2013 at University of Pennsylvania](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~brweber/Courses/2013/Math651/Notes/L18_CliffSpin.pdf) it is only said (about a similar group): "the group generated by elements $v\in V$ with $q(v) =\pm 1$" with no mention of any order between positively and negatively "normed" elements.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks for the comment. It seems my book: Mathematical Gauge Theory by J.Hamilton, tends to define $\operatorname{Spin}^+(s,t)$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Spin}(s,t)$, which is a double cover of the identity component of $\operatorname{SO}(s,t)$. He gives a proof of the above argument, but it's very concise and I don't think it makes sense, so maybe the definition above is indeed not correct, but what should such a group really looks like? I haven't seen any references mentioned this point.

Comment: Could you write down the proof?

Comment: Perhaps the group should contain elements of the form $u_1 \cdots u_{2p+2q}$ where there are $2p$ factors $u_k$ with $\eta(u_k,u_k)=1$ and $2q$ factors $u_k$ with $\eta(u_k,u_k)=-1$? That would form a group, wouldn't it.

Comment: @md2perpe I agree in this case it's a group. Let me check further whether or not the proof will makes sense in this definition. I think this indeed it's an error.

Comment: You can also contact the author [Mark J.D. Hamilton](https://www.math.lmu.de/~hamilton/).

Comment: Good advice @md2perpe

Comment: @md2perpe The author replies me and shared a link that contains the corrections of errors in his book, see edit. It turns out this indeed it's a subgroup. And the definition you suggest turns out to be equivalent to the above one.

Comment: I see, it's similar to a normal subgroup $N  \triangleleft G$ where, for any given $n\in N,\ g\in G$ you do not necessarily have $gn=ng$ but at least have $gn=n'g$ for some element $n'\in N.$ In this sense the positive and the negative spaces commute, although elements do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See EDIT in the question. It turns out that it's indeed a group, and a short proof is contained in the link attached, again, see edit.